# multiple conditions in the same SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please suggest a good way to obtain the output in the right starting from the input (left) by writing an SQL query?
We need to count the number of 'a' entries on col1 and then the number of 'b' on col2 (only for the records that have YES on Col0).

Thank you.
(Sql Server solution needed)
 [image]

Comment: MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: Sql Server, Anthony! Thank you fo raising this.

Comment: Please edit the question and add any SQL that you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
SELECT col0, SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A, SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B
FROM t
WHERE col0 = 'YES'
GROUP BY col0
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22875/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
select col0,
sum(case when col1 = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as [A],
sum(case when col2 = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) as [B]
from MyTable
where col0 = 'YES'
group by col0
```